# Ubuntu not booting from drive with the OS on it but booting from a different one

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I bought a new HDD the other day for my computer as a backup drive. I already have a SSD that has my OS on it and an additional storage drive.

However, when I plugged it in and booted my system it shows this error message:

```
This is not a bootable disk. Please insert a bootable floppy and
press any key to try again...
```

I unplugged the backup drive that I had just plugged in, thinking that was causing the issue, but the message still continued. Then I unplugged my storage drive and it finally worked.

So far I have tried to plug in both drives but nothing seems to be working. It seems like the OS is trying to boot from the storage drive/backup drive.

Upon searching, I found out that the issue might have something to do with the secure boot option, but I don't think that option exists on my systems BIOS because it's quite an old system. The only thing I can think of is boot order configurations which seem to be fine.

Comment: Yes this does look like a BIOS boot priority issue. Make sure that your BIOS/UEFI is pointing to the hard drive where Ubuntu is installed. If there are multiple entries it might be one you are assuming is the wrong one. If you're not sure about the procedure to select or change boot priority for your particular motherboard, you may need to consult its documentation

Answer (score 2):

i got it to work. i just had to change the UEFI priority for which drive to boot from.

in my case i had to specificly change the boot order of sata0, sata1, sata2 these 3 were my drives.